# How to add description and short description to product?

Tags: magento2, product

I would like to use a function to add a description and a short description, but cannot locate anything related in

> www/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/Product.php

```
//$product is an instance of Magento\Catalog\Model\Product 

$product->setDescription('suyyyper long fooBar');
//setDescription does not exist, so what would be a way to set a desscription ?
$product->setShortDescription('suyyper fooBar');
//setShortDescription does not exist, so what would be a way to set a desscription ?
```

Comment: Do you want to set it from model and want get in phtml ?

Comment: Aren't those information displayed by default on the product page ?

Comment: If not, what text is dedicated to give more information about products, to give customers a description?

Comment: If yes, I just need to add these information to the product

Comment: Hello @Crdric, Both product description and short description by default available on product page.

Comment: does description and short description is entered in admin ?

Comment: They have to be programatically entered.